# Apply post formats to a specific post type only?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, post-formats

I have the following code in functions.php to give me post format support and a custom post type 'photos'. But I would like the post formats to only apply to the 'photos' post type and not to the built-in 'posts' post type.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'image', 'chat', 'video', 'gallery' ) );
//custom post type
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'photos',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Photos' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Photo' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'photo'),
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'taxonomies' => array('genre'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'post-formats'),
        )
    );
}
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`remove_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support):

```
remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'post-formats' );
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... the format box is still there is the Posts' "Add New Post" window.

Comment: Did you hook into init?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I had to put it inside the function create_post_type. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
add_action('load-post.php','add_post_type_support_stuff');
add_action('load-post-new.php','add_post_type_support_stuff');
function add_post_type_support_stuff( $post ){

    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $post_type = $screen->post_type;

    if( $post_type == 'photos' ) {
        //add this if you did not add support for the post type when you called register_post_type()
        add_post_type_support( 'page', 'post-formats' );
        //add the post formats
        add_theme_support('post-formats',array( 'image', 'chat', 'video', 'gallery' ));
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for `$post_type = $screen->post_type;`